# Whitelisting field names to prevent malicious data manipulation?

Tags: php, security, mongodb

On a settings page I let users edit some account info like Email, Name, Password etc. Out of paranoia that they might figure out a way to sneak in additional $_post data to change their role or pollute their document with unnecessary added fields, I am using array_interest_keys on the $_post data against my whitelist of allowed fields.

```
protected $user_settings_fields = array(
    'email' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'name' => '',
);

public function edit_settings( array $data )
{
    $data = array_intersect_key($data, $this->user_settings_fields);

    // Do stuff like check $data['_id'] against auth_user['_id'] 
    // to make make sure the user is updating their own document.

    // Perform update
}
```

Is this good, common practice or overkill? I'm already taking other precautions like escaping form output data even though a buddy told me it's not necessary when using MongoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a database security standpoint, your are probably okay dumping user-submitted data into MongoDB without pulling specific fields from their POST data. However, just because MongoDB isn't vulnerable to most of the injection attacks that work on other databases does **not** mean it's a good idea to insert submitted data without validation. It is good, common practice to validate all of your fields, for several reasons.

Foremost, as you hinted at in your question, not "whitelisting" certain fields would allow a malicious user to insert a massive amount of data at once into mongo. The maximum document size in a mongo collection is 16MB. Not taking measures against this would allow an attacker to quickly fill up your hard disk with 16MB inserts (it would only take ~64 accounts per gigabyte of disk space).

Second, you should still be escaping/validating all input as best practices, especially in your whitelisted fields. In addition to obvious validations, like making sure they have submitted a valid email/username, you should **ALWAYS** escape user-submitted data on a website. Because you are using MongoDB, you don't have to worry about escaping to prevent database injection attacks, [except in certain uncommon instances](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#how-does-mongodb-address-sql-or-query-injection). However, your unescaped data could be used to do a cross-site scripting attack, allowing a user to inject malicious javascript code to, at best, insert annoying behavior into your site, and, at worst, steal people's passwords.

You can learn more about this here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

And the kind of escaping you need to do here: [How to prevent XSS with HTML/PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php)